# What is the right way to replace an entire html code block from a structure?

Tags: validation, coldfusion

My problem is that I have a from which has a text area with a wysiwyg editor.

Now, when the user submits the form and doesn't enter anything into the field this is what get's posted:  `<span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-end-marker"></span><span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-start-marker"></span><p><br></p>`

Now, I want to make the field required, and want to do validation to check if the field is empty, but it's never truly empty, because the editor places in that html.

So I though about doing something like this:

```
<cfset searchfor = "&lt;span class=&quot;sceditor-selection&quot; style=&quot;line-height: 0; display: none;&quot; id=&quot;sceditor-end-marker&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;sceditor-selection&quot; style=&quot;line-height: 0; display: none;&quot; id=&quot;sceditor-start-marker&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;">

    <cfif StructKeyExists(params.event, "summary_en")>
        <cfset 'params.event.summary_en' = Replace('params.event.summary_en', '#searchfor#', "", "All")>
    </cfif>

    <cfif params.event.summary_en eq "">
        ERROR
    <cfelse>
        PROCESS
    </cfif>
```

However, the code above does not set params.event.summary_en to "" or [empty string] as I want it to, instead it places params.event.summary_en inside of params.event.summary_en.

So for some reason my code above is replacing this: `<span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-end-marker"></span><span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-start-marker"></span><p><br></p>`

with this: `params.event.summary_en`

Any idea why this is happening, and if I'm going about this validation of the field in the right way?

Thanks.

Comment: Do not put quotes around the variable name: `Replace( 'params.event.summary_en' , ..)`. You are passing in a string, not the value of `#params.event.summary_en#`

Comment: @Leigh if I remove the quotes CF throws a construction error. Maybe because of the double scope? So I changed it to this: Replace(#params["event"]["summary_en"]#,.... but now it passes through the code and doesn't change anything at all. Setting <cfset #params["event"]["summary_en"]# = ""> set's the value that I want, so I know I'm targeting the structure correctly, but the replace function isn't working.

Comment: If those keys exists in the `params` structure, there is no reason dot notation should not work. Is `params.event.summary_en` a regular CF structure or is it something else, like an xml node? BTW, you can get rid of the `#` signs. They are not needed.

Comment: As an aside, instead of trying to work-around the problem, I would find out *why* your editor is returning html when nothing is entered. That does not sound like normal behavior...

Comment: Matt gave me the solution below, but I also like your point about the editor placing HTML inside despite nothing being entered. I've never used editors before, so I thought this was required. Are you saying, it should not be putting anything in there to begin with?

Comment: All depends on the editor (whichever one you are using?). But that behavior does sound suspicious ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below returns 'ERROR' on CF10,282462 What version of CF are you using?

```
<cfset params.event.summary_en = '<span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-end-marker"></span><span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-start-marker"></span><p><br></p>' />
<cfset searchfor = '<span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-end-marker"></span><span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-start-marker"></span><p><br></p>'>

<cfif StructKeyExists(params.event, "summary_en")>
    <cfset params.event.summary_en = Replace(params.event.summary_en,searchfor, "", "All")>
</cfif>

<cfif params.event.summary_en eq "">
    ERROR
<cfelse>
    PROCESS
</cfif>
```

Comment: Ha this works! I tried placing the unescaped HTML into my searchfor variable before...but it kept throwing errors. I thought I did have it wrapped in " (double quotes), you wrapped it in single quotes...maybe that made the difference? In any case, this is my solution! Thank you!

Comment: If you have `"` in your string you need to wrap it in `'`

Comment: I always thought " was to wrap string and ' was to wrap code that needs to be processed, but should act as a unit, so like 'form.myinput[#i#]' while using "form.myinput" would just give me the string w/o any processing. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/388-People-Please-Stop-Using-Single-Quotes-.htm what do you think about that article?

Comment: It doesn't matter which you choose, but you can't mix the ones inside the string with the ones enclosing the string. In your case your html was being parsed as cf once it hit the next ". On the subject of Nadel's blog post, it's over seven years old and is no longer an issue.

Comment: *.. and ' was to wrap code that needs to be processed* No, and in your first example it actually *prevents* CF from evaluating the FORM variable. So you still end up with a literal string ie `"form.myInput[xxxx]"` instead of the *value* of that form variable.

Comment: @Busches "but you can't mix the ones inside the string with the ones enclosing the string" Actually you can but you have to escape the quotes and it's kind of ugly. `<cfset x = "<img src = ""yourImage.jpg"" class = ""yourClass"">">`

Comment: @Travis you're correct, but that's a last resort as it's wicked ugly and much harder to read IMO.

Comment: @Busches no, I wouldn't either, under normal circumstances, but it *IS* possible and could be potentially necessary in cases where mixed quotes are used within a string. Saying it "Can't" be done is incorrect.

Comment: Thenk you very much for this guys, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

if using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library

```
<cfset jsoup = CreateObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup")>
<cfset whitelist = CreateObject("java", "org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist")>

<cfset params.event.summary_en = '<span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-end-marker"></span><span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-start-marker"></span><p><br></p>'>

<cfset safeString = Jsoup.clean(params.event.summary_en, whitelist.none())>

<cfif Len(Trim(safeString))>
    PROCESS
<cfelse>
    ERROR
</cfif>
```

I am using `whitelist.none()` just to make sure all tags are removed from string.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever have a large string that goes in and out of different quotes and you don't want to escape them you can always use [cfsavecontent](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_r-s_10.html) to save the string.

```
<cfSaveContent var = "params.event.summary_en">
<span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-end-marker"></span><span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-start-marker"></span><p><br></p>
</cfSaveContent>
```

You just need to be careful of a few nuances, for example the code above would probably work to match an exact copy of the string but the string below probably wouldn't match due to the added white space for formatting. However, it would still work great if you were just storing the value to output somewhere else.

```
<cfSaveContent var = "params.event.summary_en">
    <span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-end-marker"></span>
    <span class="sceditor-selection" style="line-height: 0; display: none;" id="sceditor-start-marker"></span>
    <p>
        <br>
    </p>
</cfSaveContent>
```

For the record, you can use the same quotes inside the string as the containing quotes but it's ugly.

```
<cfset x = "<img src = ""yourImage.jpg"" class = ""yourClass"">">
```